# How to restrict the startup of a EC2 instance if the EBS isn’t encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I would like to restrict being able to startup any ec2 instance if the storage isn’t encrypted.

Comment: how about you enable-ebs-encryption-by-default in the current region?

Comment: It is not possible to control permissions on `RunInstances` or `StartInstances` based on attributes of the attached Amazon EBS volumes. It would be easier to prevent unencrypted volumes from being created.

Comment: It would  be good have to some hooks to the AWS SDK API to do such things as mentioned in the OP. May be use aspects.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein On `RunInstances` the condition key checking for encryption can be used according to thr documentation. For starting and stopping thats not the case, there you are right!

Answer (score 1):

I see two options you have here:

1. Prevent unencrypted volumes from being created by using the `ec2:Encrypted` condition key (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-ec2_Encrypted). This condition key can also be used for the `ec2:RunInstances` action within IAM policies. Check the documentation for supported condition tags (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/User Guide/list_amazonec2.html).

Add the following policy statement to a policy  attached to the User or Role you like to enforce encryption of EBS volumes:

```yaml
Effect: Allow
Action:
- ec2:RunInstances
- ec2:CreateVolume #makes sure creating a volume separatly is also encrypted
Resource: “*”
Condition:
    Bool:
        ec2:Encrypted: True
```

2. Enable detective controls with AWS Config, which follows a more educational approach. Auto-remediation can be implemented (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/encrypted-volumes.html).

Comment: What would be the process with gojng with option 1. I never used Conditional  access keys before

Comment: I edited my answer. The policy statement can also be used on account level in a AWS organization with service control policies!

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "ec2:Encrypted": "True"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: IM getting an API error when trying to launch AMI "An error occurred describing your selected AMI
You are not authorized to perform this operation."

Comment: Keep in mind the `ec2:*` action wildcard will prevent ANY action for ec2 where the request flag `ec2:Encrypted` does not exist. Read the red box on the top here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html). Create on statement allow without condition and one for only the applying actions with condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can now turn on encryption for EBS by default.

[image: EBS settings]

[image: Default encryption]